# Duvida sobre ponteiros e alocação dinamica

Tags: c, alocação

Estou tendo dificuldades em fazer essa atividade. Se possivel, me dêem dicas e soluções pra melhorar o codigo. E me expliquem porque o compilador consegue rodar o programa porem ao chegar na parte final da opcao CADASTRO ele da erro. Quem poder rodar o programa no seu compilador pra testa e ver o que to querendo dizer , agradeço muito.Desconfio que o problema seja com ponteiros ou com a alocação dinâmica feita.

> Faça um programa que realize o cadastro de clientes de um banco. Cada
>   cliente tem um nome, um sobrenome, um endereço, um e-mail, um
>   telefone, um cpf e um identificador. Um cliente pode ter um dos quatro
>   tipos de conta permitidas pelo banco: corrente, salário, poupança e
>   universitária. Para cada um dos tipos, há tipos diferentes de
>   clientes. Para a conta universitária, o cliente deve estudante e deve
>   possuir matrícula, data da matrícula, previsão de conclusão, curso e
>   universidade. Para a conta poupança, devem ser armazenadas as
>   informações de quando o cliente depositou o dinheiro e quanto rendeu
>   no último mês. Para a conta salário, o cliente deve ter um salário,
>   órgão em que trabalha, cargo, data da contratação. A conta corrente é
>   para os demais casos e não tem uma informação específica. Todas as
>   contas devem conter uma agência e um número.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>



typedef struct{
    int dia,mes,ano;
}data;

typedef struct {
    char matricula[10];
    data _matricula;
    data _conclusao;
    char curso[25];
    char universidade[50];

}universitario;

typedef struct {
    data _deposito;
    float renda;    
}poupanca;

typedef struct {

    float salario;
    char orgao_trabalha[50];
    char cargo[12];
    data _contratacao;
}salario;


typedef struct{ 

}corrente;

typedef struct {

    char nome [25];
    char sobrenome[25];
    char endereco[50];
    char email[25];
    char telefone[12];
    char CPF[12];
    int ID;
    int  agencia;
    int numero;
union {
     universitario u;   
     poupanca p;
     salario s;
     corrente c;
    }conta_tipo;
}cadastro;

// VARIAVEL GLOBAL
cadastro *c1;
int k=1;
// ENUM
enum funcao_menu{cadastrar=1,remover,alterar_cliente,alterar_conta,saque_deposito,rendimento,exibir
};
enum saque_deposito{saque=1,deposito
};
enum conta_tipo{univer=1,poup,salar,corren
};

// PROTOTIPAGEM DE FUNÇOES
void funcao_menu ();
void ler_codigo(int n);
void preencher_cadastro (cadastro *p,int tipo_conta,int k);
void exibir_cliente (cadastro *p,int k);

//FUNCAO PRINCIPAL

int main () {
int funcao;
// INICIO DO MENU PRINCIPAL
funcao_menu();
scanf ("%i",&funcao);
ler_codigo(funcao);


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}


// Funcao Menu

void funcao_menu (){

printf ("Banco Caraca\n\n");
printf ("-Cadastro de Clientes-\n\n");
printf ("Menu Principal\n--------------\n");
printf ("1-Cadastrar Cliente\n");
printf ("2-Remover Cliente\n");
printf ("3-Alterar Cliente\n");
printf ("4-Alterar Tipo De Conta\n");
printf ("5-Realizar Saque ou Deposito\n");
printf ("6-Calcular Rendimento da Poupanca\n");
printf ("7-Exibir clientes cadastrados\n");
printf ("---------------------------------\n");
printf ("Insira o codigo numerico da funcao: ");    
}


// Funcao de leitura e preenchimento de dados 

void ler_codigo(int n){
    int opcao;
        c1 = (cadastro *) malloc(sizeof(cadastro));
switch (n){

    case 1:{
        int tipo_conta;
        printf ("Cadastrar Cliente\n");
        printf ("-----------------\n");
        printf("Insira o codigo numerico do tipo de conta:\n");
        printf("1-Universitario\n");
        printf("2-Poupanca\n");
        printf("3-Salario\n");
        printf("4-Corrente\n");
        printf("--------------\n");
        printf("Opcao Escolhida:  ");
        scanf ("%i",&tipo_conta);
            switch (tipo_conta){
                case univer:{
                printf ("Conta Universitario\n");
                printf ("-------------------\n");

                preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
                break;
            }
                case poup:{
                printf ("Conta Poupanca\n");
                printf ("--------------\n");
                preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
                break;
            }

                case salar:{
                printf ("Conta Salario\n");
                printf ("-------------\n");
                preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
                break;
            }

                case corren:{
                printf ("Conta Corrente\n");
                printf ("--------------\n");
                preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
                break;
            }



        }

        break;
    }

    case 2:{
        printf("Remover Cliente\n");
        printf("---------------\n");

        break;
    }   
    case 3:{
        printf ("Alterar Cliente\n");
        printf ("----------------\n");

        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        printf ("Alterar Tipo De Conta\n");
        printf ("---------------------\n");

        break;
    }
    case 5:{
        printf ("Realizar Saque ou Deposito\n");
        printf ("Insira a opcao:\n");
        printf ("1-Saque\n");
        printf ("2-Deposito\n");
        printf ("----------\n");
        printf("Opcao Escolhida: ");    
        scanf ("%i",&opcao);
            if (opcao==saque){
            printf ("Realizar Saque\n");
            printf ("--------------\n");

        }

            else if(opcao==deposito){
            printf("Realizar Deposito\n");
            printf("-----------------\n");

        }

            else if (opcao!=deposito||opcao!=saque){
            printf("Opcao Invalida.Tente Novamente.");

        }
            break;
    }

    case 6:{    
        printf ("Calcular Rendimento Da Poupança\n");
        printf ("-------------------------------\n");
        break;
    }
    case 7:{    
        printf ("Exibir clientes cadastrados\n");
        printf ("-------------------------------\n");
        exibir_cliente(c1,k);
        break;
    }


    default :{
        printf ("Opcao Invalida.Tente Novamente.\n");
        break;
    }
}

}

// FUNÇÃO DE EXIBIR CLIENTES

void exibir_cliente (cadastro *p,int k){
    int i;
    printf("Clientes cadastrados: \n ----------------------------------------- \n");
    printf("Nome\n");
    for (i=1;i<=k;i++){
        printf("%s",(p+i)->nome);   
    }

}
// FUNÇÃO DE PREENCHIMENTO GERAL DO CADASTRO

    void preencher_cadastro (cadastro *p,int tipo_conta,int k){

        printf ("Insira o nome do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        fgets ((p+k)->nome,25,stdin);
        printf("Insira o sobrenome do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        fgets ((p+k)->sobrenome,25,stdin);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf("Insira o endereco do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        fgets ((p+k)->endereco,50,stdin);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf("Insira o e-mail do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        fgets ((p+k)->email,25,stdin);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf("Insira o telefone (com DD) do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        fgets ((p+k)->telefone,12,stdin); b
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf("Insira o CPF do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        fgets ((p+k)->CPF,12,stdin);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);    

        switch (tipo_conta){

        case univer:{     

            printf ("Insira o nome da universidade do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
            fgets ((p+k)->conta_tipo.u.universidade,50,stdin);
            setbuf (stdin,NULL);
            printf ("Insira o curso de graducao do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
            fgets ((p+k)->conta_tipo.u.curso,25,stdin);   
            setbuf (stdin,NULL);                                 
            printf ("Insira a matricula institucional do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
            fgets ((p+k)->conta_tipo.u.matricula,10,stdin);
            printf ("Insira a data de matricula do curso do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
            setbuf (stdin,NULL);
            scanf("%i%i%",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._matricula.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._matricula.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._matricula.ano);
            setbuf (stdin,NULL);
            printf ("Insira a data de conclusao de curso do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
            scanf("%i%i%",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._conclusao.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._conclusao.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._conclusao.ano);
            setbuf (stdin,NULL);

            break;
        }
        case poup:{

            printf ("Insira a data do deposito:  ");
            scanf ("%i%i%i",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.p._deposito.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.p._deposito.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.p._deposito.ano);
            // chamar a funcao pra calcular o quanto rendeu (JOAO VITOR);
            break;
        }

        case salar:{
            printf("Insira o valor em reais do salario: R$  ");
            scanf("%f",(p+k)->conta_tipo.s.salario);
            printf("Insira o nome do orgao em que o cliente trabalha:  ");
            fgets((p+k)->conta_tipo.s.orgao_trabalha,50,stdin);
            printf("Insira o cargo profissional ocupado pelo cliente:  ");
            fgets((p+k)->conta_tipo.s.cargo,12,stdin);
            printf("Insira a data de contracao profissional do cliente:  ");
            scanf("%i%i%i",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.s._contratacao.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.s._contratacao.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.s._contratacao.ano);
            break;
        }

        case corren:{
            break;
        }

    default :{
        printf("Opcao Invalida.Tente Novamente.");
        break;
    }   
    }
    c1 = (cadastro *) realloc(c1, (k+1)*sizeof(cadastro));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>



typedef struct{
    int dia,mes,ano;
}data;

typedef struct {
   char matricula[10];
   data _matricula;
   data _conclusao;
   char curso[25];
   char universidade[50];

}universitario;

typedef struct {
   data _deposito;
   float renda;
}poupanca;

typedef struct {
   float salario;
   char orgao_trabalha[50];
   char cargo[12];
   data _contratacao;
}salario;


 typedef struct{

 }corrente;

 typedef struct {
   char nome [25];
   char sobrenome[25];
   char endereco[50];
   char email[25];
   char telefone[12];
   char CPF[12];
   int ID;
   int  agencia;
   int numero;
 union {
   universitario u;
   poupanca p;
   salario s;
   corrente c;
 }conta_tipo;
}cadastro;

// VARIAVEL GLOBAL
cadastro *c1;
int k=1;

// ENUM
enum funcao_menu{cadastrar=1,remover,alterar_cliente,alterar_conta,
saque_deposito, rendimento,exibir};
enum saque_deposito{saque=1,deposito};
enum conta_tipo{univer=1,poup,salar,corren};

// PROTOTIPAGEM DE FUNÇOES
void funcao_menu ();
void ler_codigo(int n);
void preencher_cadastro (cadastro *p,int tipo_conta,int k);
void exibir_cliente (cadastro *p,int k);


//FUNCAO PRINCIPAL
int main () {
  int funcao;
  // INICIO DO MENU PRINCIPAL
  funcao_menu();
  scanf ("%i",&funcao);
  ler_codigo(funcao);
  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}


// Funcao Menu
void funcao_menu (){ 
  printf ("Banco Caraca\n\n");
  printf ("-Cadastro de Clientes-\n\n");
  printf ("Menu Principal\n--------------\n");
  printf ("1-Cadastrar Cliente\n");
  printf ("2-Remover Cliente\n");
  printf ("3-Alterar Cliente\n");
  printf ("4-Alterar Tipo De Conta\n");
  printf ("5-Realizar Saque ou Deposito\n");
  printf ("6-Calcular Rendimento da Poupanca\n");
  printf ("7-Exibir clientes cadastrados\n");
  printf ("---------------------------------\n");
  printf ("Insira o codigo numerico da funcao: ");
}


 // Funcao de leitura e preenchimento de dados

void ler_codigo(int n){
    int opcao;
    c1 = (cadastro *) malloc(sizeof(cadastro));
switch (n){

case 1:{
    int tipo_conta;
    printf ("Cadastrar Cliente\n");
    printf ("-----------------\n");
    printf("Insira o codigo numerico do tipo de conta:\n");
    printf("1-Universitario\n");
    printf("2-Poupanca\n");
    printf("3-Salario\n");
    printf("4-Corrente\n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("Opcao Escolhida:  ");
    scanf ("%i",&tipo_conta);
        switch (tipo_conta){
            case univer:{
            printf ("Conta Universitario\n");
            printf ("-------------------\n");

            preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
            break;
        }
            case poup:{
            printf ("Conta Poupanca\n");
            printf ("--------------\n");
            preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
            break;
        }

            case salar:{
            printf ("Conta Salario\n");
            printf ("-------------\n");
            preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
            break;
        }

            case corren:{
            printf ("Conta Corrente\n");
            printf ("--------------\n");
            preencher_cadastro (c1,tipo_conta,k);
            break;
        }



    }

    break;
}

case 2:{
    printf("Remover Cliente\n");
    printf("---------------\n");

    break;
}
case 3:{
    printf ("Alterar Cliente\n");
    printf ("----------------\n");

    break;
}
case 4: {
    printf ("Alterar Tipo De Conta\n");
    printf ("---------------------\n");

    break;
}
case 5:{
    printf ("Realizar Saque ou Deposito\n");
    printf ("Insira a opcao:\n");
    printf ("1-Saque\n");
    printf ("2-Deposito\n");
    printf ("----------\n");
    printf("Opcao Escolhida: ");
    scanf ("%i",&opcao);
        if (opcao==saque){
        printf ("Realizar Saque\n");
        printf ("--------------\n");

    }

        else if(opcao==deposito){
        printf("Realizar Deposito\n");
        printf("-----------------\n");

    }

        else if (opcao!=deposito||opcao!=saque){
        printf("Opcao Invalida.Tente Novamente.");

    }
        break;
}

case 6:{
    printf ("Calcular Rendimento Da Poupança\n");
    printf ("-------------------------------\n");
    break;
}
case 7:{
    printf ("Exibir clientes cadastrados\n");
    printf ("-------------------------------\n");
    exibir_cliente(c1,k);
    break;
}


 default :{
    printf ("Opcao Invalida.Tente Novamente.\n");
     break;
  }
 }

}

// FUNÇÃO DE EXIBIR CLIENTES
  void exibir_cliente (cadastro *p,int k){
    int i;
    printf("Clientes cadastrados: \n --------------------------------------- 
    -- \n");
    printf("Nome\n");
    for (i=1;i<=k;i++){
        printf("%s",(p+i)->nome);
    }
 }

 // FUNÇÃO DE PREENCHIMENTO GERAL DO CADASTRO
   void preencher_cadastro (cadastro *p,int tipo_conta,int k){
     printf ("Insira o nome do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
     fflush(stdin);
     fgets ((p+k)->nome,25,stdin);
    printf("Insira o sobrenome do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets ((p+k)->sobrenome,25,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Insira o endereco do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
    fgets ((p+k)->endereco,50,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Insira o e-mail do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets ((p+k)->email,25,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Insira o telefone (com DD) do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets ((p+k)->telefone,12,stdin); c
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Insira o CPF do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
    fgets ((p+k)->CPF,12,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    switch (tipo_conta){

    case univer:{

        printf ("Insira o nome da universidade do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        fgets ((p+k)->conta_tipo.u.universidade,50,stdin);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf ("Insira o curso de graducao do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        fgets ((p+k)->conta_tipo.u.curso,25,stdin);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf ("Insira a matricula institucional do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        fgets ((p+k)->conta_tipo.u.matricula,10,stdin);
        printf ("Insira a data de matricula do curso do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        scanf("%i%i%",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._matricula.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._matricula.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._matricula.ano);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);
        printf ("Insira a data de conclusao de curso do cliente a ser cadastrado:  ");
        scanf("%i%i%",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._conclusao.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._conclusao.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.u._conclusao.ano);
        setbuf (stdin,NULL);

        break;
    }
    case poup:{

        printf ("Insira a data do deposito:  ");
        scanf ("%i%i%i",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.p._deposito.dia,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.p._deposito.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.p._deposito.ano);
        // chamar a funcao pra calcular o quanto rendeu (JOAO VITOR);
        break;
    }

    case salar:{
        printf("Insira o valor em reais do salario: R$  ");
        scanf("%f",(p+k)->conta_tipo.s.salario);
        printf("Insira o nome do orgao em que o cliente trabalha:  ");
        fgets((p+k)->conta_tipo.s.orgao_trabalha,50,stdin);
        printf("Insira o cargo profissional ocupado pelo cliente:  ");
        fgets((p+k)->conta_tipo.s.cargo,12,stdin);
        printf("Insira a data de contracao profissional do cliente:  ");
        scanf("%i%i%i",&(p+k)->conta_tipo.s._contratacao.dia,&(p+k)- 
      >conta_tipo.s._contratacao.mes,&(p+k)->conta_tipo.s._contratacao.ano);
        break;
    }

    case corren:{
        break;
    }

default :{
    printf("Opcao Invalida.Tente Novamente.");
    break;
  }
 }
  p = (cadastro *) realloc(c1, (k+1)*sizeof(cadastro));
}
```

O seu problema estava só na importação da biblioteca  e em uma chave não colocada kkkk
Não encontrei nenhum problema relacionado a sua alocação, mas vou continuar a dar mais uma olhada no código e no exercício.

Uma dica: você poderia colocar um sistema de repetição na hora de mostrar as notas, para caso o usuário queira voltar ao menu sem que o programa encerre.

Comment: idente melhor a sua resposta para que seja mais fácil o entendimento